# Проблема с доступом к VirusTotal API (403)

Tags: c#, api, virustotal

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос к VtAPI на сканирование файла, но кидает ошибку 403

Ключ точно правильный, несколько раз проверял.

Вот страница с примером использования API ключа https://developers.virustotal.com/v2.0/reference/file-scan

Вот так отправляю API запрос:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var apiKey = "";
        var filePath = "C:/exmpl/exmpl.jpg";

        var result = await ScanFileWithVirusTotal(apiKey, filePath);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static async Task<string> ScanFileWithVirusTotal(string apiKey, string filePath)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        string fileBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var requestContent = new StringContent($"{{\"apikey\":\"{apiKey}\",\"file\":\"{fileBase64}\"}}");
            requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var requestUri = new Uri("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan");

            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseBody;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: а откуда вы взяли такой json формат, в документации запрос нужно дулать по другому https://developers.virustotal.com/v2.0/reference/file-scan

Comment: Попробуйте вариант с документации, боюсь все равно будет ошибка 403. Я переделал метод как в документации, ничего не поменялось, да и мой метод буквально идентичен тому что в документации, просто подход другой.

Comment: Я вам советую использовать свежий API [V3](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/files-scan), там более понятней будет что да как. Что касается 2-й версии, то документация там немного лукавит, и примеры не совсем верны. Сайт от вас вроде как просит не JSON, а `multipart/form-data`, где в одной части будет ключ, в другой будет файл (об этом кстати в документации свидетельствует пример, в котором используется `-form`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял в v3 api они разделили загрузку файла и получение результата сканирования файла. Есть два апи:

- https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/files-scan - для загрузки файла
- https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/analysis - для получения результата сканирования

Примерный тестовый код:

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

// общая конфигурации для клиента
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.virustotal.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-apikey", "<your_key>");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));

// загрузка файла, после успешной загрузки вы получаете id
var id = await UploadFile(client);

// тут нужна пауза на "некоторое время" пока файл не обработается

// проверка статуса по id
var result = await GetStatus(client, id);

// если в result есть status: queued - файл в обработке
// если в result есть status: completed - отчет готов
// документация про формат этого ответа https://developers.virustotal.com/reference/analyses-object
Console.WriteLine(result);

return;

async Task<string> UploadFile(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(@"<path_to_file>")), "file", "<file_name>");

    using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/v3/files", content);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var body = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<VTResponse<VTAnalysis>>();

    return body.data.id;
}

async Task<string> GetStatus(HttpClient httpClient, string id)
{
    using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"api/v3/analyses/{id}");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return body;
}

// временные классы для получения ответа
public record VTResponse<T>(T data);

public record VTAnalysis(string id, string type);
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо за предоставленный код!